# PHPUnit problem - no error messages

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time.

I have a simple PHPUnit test case with 2 tests. When I run it, I get this output:

```
PHPUnit 3.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.
```

So the first assertion runs, passes. The second assertion, however, causes some PHP error (exception or something), and PHPUnit just dies without any info about what could have gone wrong.

Here is my phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="false"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="true"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Portal Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/OneSolution/Portal/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Setting `syntaxCheck` to `true` doesn't give any additional information about the error. However, it does print twice (before running any tests) that `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

**???**

So, does anyone have any ideas what could I do to make PHPUnit report those error messages (the `--verbose` option didn't help either)?

**EDIT:** I've found out what has been causing the test to fail. There was a mistyped method name (I rely too much on code assist, I guess). However, this doesn't solve the main problem. *Any warnings, errors or exception go unreported by PHPUnit*.

Comment: Yes. If I comment out the assertion in the second test, they both pass and PHPUnit finishes normally (i. e. it prints out memory consumption info etc.) If I delete the first (working) test, it dies after hitting the second assertion.

Comment: Reporting syntax errors is up to PHP.  Verify your error reporting configuration in php.ini

Comment: _I rely too much on code assist, I guess_ -- Get yourself a better IDE then -- something that can highlight unknown method name/misspelled variable/etc (like NetBeans or PhpStorm, for example).

Comment: OK, so `error_reporting` was set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. However, `display_errors` was set to off. Sorry to bother with something so stupid, I forgot to setup my fresh install properly.

Comment: If that's the solution, go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: If you don't know which test it's failing on (if you have a lot) you can run phpunit --debug

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, so if anyone has trouble with getting none or incomplete output from PHPUnit command line, double-check your `php.ini` configuration directives:

- `error_reporting` - should be set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` for your development environment
- `display_errors` - should be set to `On`

Comment: On PHP >=5.4 you only need to use E_ALL, since E_STRICT is a part of E_ALL.

Comment: The author of the software package I was modifying had hardcoded error_reporting(E_STRICT) into bootstrap.php, so that's worth checking too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, even with all error reporting enabled.

I tried to put `echo` statements into my test and `setUp` methods to find out where it was hanging, but they never appeared. The problem turned out to be PHP's output buffering. When I added the following method to my test:

```
protected function debug($text)
{
    echo "\nDEBUG: $text\n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

and used `$this->debug()` instead of plain `echo`, I was able to see my debug statements. A binary search through the code quickly led to the source of the problem (an invalid database fixture, in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I used the `--debug` flag to pinpoint last test ran before output faded to nothingness. Then, I drilled my way down from that test to the method run before swallowing all output. Let's call it `blackHole()`. You can either move that call to its own test or quickly run it in the errant context

In my case, the problem was partly from `blackHole()`, and partly from its dependency. Changes had been made to `blackHole()`, but all their tests hadn't been run ever since. Then, its dependency had multiple errors (system-level/syntax errors like invalid interface implementation, most important. Then unexpected type supplied as argument). After correcting them, fixtures, all its tests passing etc, the original SUT started going through.

I believe PHPUnit reaches a point of no return when it encounters such low level errors outside the test scope. Or, it could have a small memory limit that a deeply nested exception can overflow, resulting in a crash. Since all output is buffered until run completion, nothing makes it out to the terminal