# phpunit + Symfony2: There is no message specifying which tests are failing

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

When I run phpunit -c app this is the output:

```
PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

WF.FFF..............                                              20 / 20 
(100%)

Time: 19.65 seconds, Memory: 18.00Mb

There was 1 warning:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "Sheik\RobotBundle\Tests\Controller\CrawlerControllerTest".

WARNINGS!
Tests: 20, Assertions: 21, Failures: 4, Warnings: 1.
```

I am working with Symfony 2.5 in Ubuntu 16.04. Before updating to Ubuntu 16.04 there use to be a message for each failure specifying which test was failing.

Here is my app/phpunit.xml.dist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

I tried the sugestions in this other question:
[PHPUnit problem - no error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378845/phpunit-problem-no-error-messages?rq=1)
but error_reporting was already set to E_ALL | E_STRICT and display_errors  to On in my php.ini.

I will apreciate any other sugestions or tips.

Comment: try executing `phpunit` with verbose option enabled: `phpunit -v`

Comment: the --verbose option didn't help. It just adds This line to the output: `Configuration: /var/www/newsheikit/app/phpunit.xml.dist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, and maybe it could help someone as work around, using
 `phpunit -c app src/yourVendor/yourBundle/Tests/`
will display the missing messages of failure with each route to the failing test.